# How to navigate to a page in react native that is not in the tab navigator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, tabs

I have this in my react-native code:

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: Home,
  "Exercise List": ExerciseList,
  Exercise: Exercise,
  "Current Workout": CurrentWorkout,
})
```

but I only want to navigate to the Exercise tab when I click to it via the exerciseList page like so:

`onPress={() => navigate("Exercise", { name: item.name })}`

and I don't want it to appear in the navigation bar at the bottom. But if I remove it from `MainNavigator` above then it doesn't work when I click the onPress above. Is there a way to Navigate to the component without it being in the tab nav?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make some change in app.js. add createBottomTabNavigator inside createStackNavigator. Add those component into stacknavigator in which you do not want to add into bottom tab navigator. In createBottomTabNavigator add those component which you want to show in tab bar

Please check following code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import LoginScreen from "./Screens/LoginScreen";
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <StackNav />;
  }
}
const StackNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    TabNavigator: {
      screen: AppTabNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null
      }
    },
    First: {
      screen: First,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null
      }
    },
    Second: {
      screen: Second,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "TabNavigator"
  }
);
const AppTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen
  }
});
```

Comment: for some reason I couldn't understand stacknavigator until I read this!  Thanks, this was super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Add it with `createSwitchNavigator`. A working example is given below

```
const Navigation = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
        App: AppStack,
        Auth: AuthStack,
        Qr: QrPage,


    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
```

Here I can access to my Qr page from any where.

Answer (score 0):

here is two method of of call other components which doesn't contains in `tabNavigator`:

```
 const otherAppNavigator = createStackNavigator({//all of this are not in TabNavigator
dashboard: {
    screen: Dashboard,
},

userProfile: {
    screen: UserProfile
},

onGoingPickup: {
    screen: OnGoingPickup
},
 });

    const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    home: otherAppNavigator,//<<<<<<<<<<
    about:foo,

       }
    )

const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    firstPage: {//it's not in TabNavigator<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        screen: Login,
    },
    verification: {//its not in TabNavigator<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        screen: verification
    },
    dashboard: {
        screen: TabNavigator
    }
})

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator); //the main navigator is which you bind in here
```

pay attention to the last line ....!!!!

hope to be helpful.